# Blogger API 4.0 nextPageToken not generating the next set of posts

Tags: api, token, blogger

I'm using the Blogger API to fetch blog posts, and I receive the next Page Token. From my understanding you're supposed to add that key into the next request, however I keep getting the same posts again and not the next set of posts. Whether I set the max posts or not it will return only 10 posts.

Below is the initial fetch request where I'm making a query to the search bar (empty state is `searchPost`), and I save the data in the `posts` state.

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
  axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/7439681026540002213/posts/search?q=${this.state.searchPost}&fetchBodies=true&fetchImages=true&orderBy=published&status=live&view=READER&key=${process.env.REACT_APP_BLOGGER_API}`)
  .then(res=>{
    this.setState({posts:res.data.items})
  })
  .catch(err=>{
    console.log(err)
  })
 }
```

I then made a method `nextPage` where it should make another call to get the next page and repopulate the posts state with the new data (or at least that's what I think the code is doing).

```
nextPage = () => {
  axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/7439681026540002213/posts/search?q=${this.state.searchPost}&fetchBodies=true&fetchImages=true&orderBy=published&status=live&view=READER&key=${process.env.REACT_APP_BLOGGER_API}&pageToken=CgkIChjAwbDpnCoQpbeF6Z_Pw59n`)
  .then(res => {
    this.setState({posts:res.data.items});
  })
  .catch(err=>{
    console.log(err)
  }
  )}
```

Answer (score 1):

`pageToken` works only with method [list](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/list), you can't use it with search method;
I think these are the only parameters that work with it:

**blogId**, **q**, fetchBodies, orderBy, alt, fields, prettyPrint

Comment: Ah what a shame. I'm just wondering why it returns with a next page token in the first place then?